# In Xubuntu, should I always install everything in the Update Manager?

Tags: updates, xubuntu, update-manager

I have been running Xubuntu 12.10 for over a month now, on 5 machines (old Compaq Evos, runs nice and slim on these old chips).  I immediately became afraid of installing the updates suggested in the Update Manager when an update session in one machine disabled the wireless card I had worked so hard to get working (one of those pesky ones that refuses to play nice with Linux).

I later noticed that some updates in the Update Manager don't seem to apply to me, such as a "Unity Toolbar Update".  I installed this version of Ubuntu cleanly as Xubuntu so I don't use Unity.

**To summarize my question: Should I always install everything that comes up in the Update Manager in Xubuntu or would it be better to skip updates that I think should not apply to my machine?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only install what you want :) Don't fix what's not broken.

Comment: I had been going in this direction, not installing any update that didn't seem useful to me, but they are piling up.

Answer (score 0):

I think at a minimum you should do security updates, which includes the kernel.

It is rare that updates cause problems, but in the event they do you should have a working backup of your data.

Answer (score 0):

I install everything that comes up. If there is an update for a package, why not install it?

Now, while no update is guaranteed to work your specific setup, security updates are important, and other updates basically install new versions of programs that you have installed.

Also you can read the Change log to see what each update provides.